# How do I get into contact with the IRS to ask some tax questions?

Tags: united-states, taxes, irs

Way back in March I filed my taxes, and applied for a payment plan. My request actually never went through, and I ended up having to re-apply on April 20th. The representative I talked to said that my plan would start in May and would end in August.

Since then I have received 3 letters from the IRS; the first one came around the first week of May, and stated that my taxes weren't done processing, so my payment plan wasn't active yet. The next two letters were notifications telling me to cancel my payment plan if I didn't sign up for one. Then nothing.

I would like to get in contact with the IRS, and talk to an actual person about the status of my plan and ask the following questions: Should I be making payments if it isn't done processing? Will my payment plan begin once my taxes are done processing? Will I be held responsible for money owed in May if I did not receive any sort of notification informing me of the obligation?

The question I am asking here is just how to reasonably get into contact with the IRS. How can I talk to someone who can find all these answers for me? Their web portal for payment agreements has never worked for me, and all the phone numbers are just touch tone mazes filled with dead ends.

I really would like to be able to budget for my future, but I have no clue what the IRS is expecting of me at this time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best bet might be to visit a local [IRS office](https://www.irs.gov/uac/contact-your-local-irs-office-1) in person.

To find your local office, use the [IRS office locator page](https://apps.irs.gov/app/officeLocator/index.jsp).  After you enter your zip code and find your nearest office, click on the "hours and services" link, which will show you a list of every office in your state.  For each office, you can click on the "services provided" link to make sure that they handle "payment arrangements" at your selected office.  Finally, you should probably call the local office first to see if you need an appointment, so you don't have to wait.

Comment: Thank you, I was hoping to avoid that option because now I have to call off from work to make the trip, but this seems like my only option.

Comment: I also want to add that if you contact the Taxpayers Assistance Center at 1-844-545-5640 they will try to remedy any problem you have before setting up an in person appointment. Sadly my situation was much more complex that I realized, so I am still going to the office in person.